# Adding a new cookie upon user registration

Tags: plone

I'm using plone4.1 and would like to create a cookie for my whole domain (.site.com) when a user logs in on the web site. This cookie will be read by other sites/applications in my domain. Alternatively changing "__ac" to apply to the domain instead of www.site.com.

I've seen from other questions that `setCookie(...)` would do it. I would like to create the cookie on a successful login. Where would be a good place to do this?

Thanks for your help, I'm new to plone programming.

Answer (score 4):

You can set the domain in the session plugin (controlling the `__ac` cookie).

1. Go to the ZMI via the Site Setup control panel:
   [image: ZMI link]
2. Find the `acl_users` folder:
   [image: acl_users link]
3. Inside of this folder is a `session` object:
   [image: session link]
4. This in turn has a `Properties` tab:
   [image: properties tab]
5. On that tab, there is a `Cookie domain` field:
   [image: Cookie domain field]

Here, fill in your `.site.com` domain and hit `Save Changes`.

Comment: Sticking to [SO cultural memes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19775/140890) is important! :-)